# Get value from iframe in plain javascript

Tags: javascript

I have this code:

```
<iframe src="iframe.html"></iframe>

    <script>
        // Get the iframe element
        const iframe = document.getElementsByTagName('iframe')[0];

        // Check if the iframe has loaded
        iframe.onload = function () {
            // Access the iframe's content document
            const iframeDocument = iframe.contentDocument || iframe.contentWindow;

            // Now you can interact with the content
            console.log(iframeDocument);
        };
    </script>
```

I need write in my console.log content from iframe.

In this moment i have nothing:(

Hoiw can i repair it?

Comment: try using `contentWindow.document` or `iframe.contentDocument` to ensure cross-browser compatibility. And also your `onload` might not fire if the iframe is already loaded when your script runs

Comment: you think about somethink like this: const elements = document.getElementsByTagName('iframe');
        const content = elements['0'].contentWindow.document;
        console.log(content); ?

Comment: First, make that `const iframeDocument = iframe.contentDocument || iframe.contentWindow.document;`, so that in both cases, you will be dealing with a document instance. And then, `console.log(iframeDocument.documentElement.outerHTML)`